# Can not render array within FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have read all similar questions in stack overflow on this topic. Yet my info is not being displayed.

I am fetching locations from tomtom api. I have limit the result up to one location for simplicity. My data:

```
items:  Array [
  Object {
    "address": Object {
      "country": "United States",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "countryCodeISO3": "USA",
      "countrySecondarySubdivision": "Hidalgo",
      "countrySubdivision": "TX",
      "countrySubdivisionName": "Texas",
      "extendedPostalCode": "78542-7214",
      "freeformAddress": "1718 South 28th Avenue, Edinburg, TX 78542",
      "localName": "Edinburg",
      "municipality": "Edinburg",
      "postalCode": "78542",
      "streetName": "South 28th Avenue",
      "streetNumber": "1718",
    },
    "dist": 7911851.058335642,
    "entryPoints": Array [
      Object {
        "position": Object {
          "lat": 26.28239,
          "lon": -98.14742,
        },
        "type": "main",
      },
    ],
    "id": "840489007442969",
    "info": "search:ta:840489007442969-US",
    "poi": Object {
      "categories": Array [
        "company",
        "equipment rental",
      ],
      "categorySet": Array [
        Object {
          "id": 9352038,
        },
      ],
      "classifications": Array [
        Object {
          "code": "COMPANY",
          "names": Array [
            Object {
              "name": "equipment rental",
              "nameLocale": "en-US",
            },
            Object {
              "name": "company",
              "nameLocale": "en-US",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      "name": "Wylie Implement Edinbu",
      "phone": "+1 956-550-8822",
    },
    "position": Object {
      "lat": 26.28223,
      "lon": -98.1464,
    },
    "score": 1.9846990108,
    "type": "POI",
    "viewport": Object {
      "btmRightPoint": Object {
        "lat": 26.2813,
        "lon": -98.14536,
      },
      "topLeftPoint": Object {
        "lat": 26.28316,
        "lon": -98.14744,
      },
    },
  },
]
```

My component:

```
const AutocompleteResults = (props) => {
  const [locations, setLocations] = useState(props.items);
  console.log("items: ", locations);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocations(props.items);
  }, [props.items]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <Text>Result</Text>
    {locations.length>0 ? (
        <>
          <Text>Items</Text>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 1 }}
            horizontal={false}
            data={locations}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({location}) => {
              console.log("single location ", location);
              return <Text>Location</Text>;
            }}
          />
        </>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default AutocompleteResults;
```

What I see on the console is: `single location  undefined`

I tried all the suggestions which I found in stack overflow. In my opinion the problem is in `extractKey` method but I dont know how to fix it.

On the screen I just see the words "Result" "Items" followed by red dash (coming from my styling for flatlist)

**EDIT**:

I edited my render function in the following way:

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {
              console.log("single location ", item);
              return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 30 }}>
                  <Text>Location</Text>
                </View>
              );
            }}
```

But the "Location" text still does not display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destructuring `location` in the `renderItem` function of the `FlatList`. This fails, because there is no such parameter. The parameter is called `item`.

This is explained in [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

> renderItem({ item, index, separators });
>
> item (Object): The item from data being rendered.

The following code should fix the issue.

```js
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 20 }}>
      <Text>Result</Text>
    {locations.length>0 ? (
        <>
          <Text>Items</Text>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 1 }}
            horizontal={false}
            data={locations}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
              console.log("single location ", item);
              return <Text>Location</Text>;
            }}
          />
        </>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The `extractKey` function is fine.

Comment: Exactly as David mentions, here is a sandbox of your code to prove:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-pond-kl8oz0?file=/src/AutocompleteResults.js

Comment: @David I do see item being logged on the console, which is fine, but I still dont see any text  "Location" being displayed on the screen. Do you have any idea why?